# Rails: prevent division by zero with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have my rails app with a postgre database and I'm trying to get some indicators, with the following statement

```
Negotiation.find(:all, :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), :select => 'sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / sum(amount_after_annualised_base) as pt').first
```

how can I make sure that sum(amount_after_annualised_base) is not 0 (thus doesn't throw a "division by zero" error)?

I've found this, but not sure it is correct / the best / most efficient way.

```
Negotiation.find(:all, :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), :select => 'sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / (CASE sum(amount_after_annualised_base) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(amount_after_annualised_base) END) as pt').first
```

thanks!
Pierre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [nullif](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-conditional.html#AEN15284):

```
Negotiation.find(:all, :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), :select => 'sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / nullif(sum(amount_after_annualised_base),0) as pt').first
```

which is just a consise shorthand for your solution:

```
Negotiation.find(:all, :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), :select => 'sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / (CASE sum(amount_after_annualised_base) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(amount_after_annualised_base) END) as pt').first
```

Comment: Does this work? Because you still try to do a division in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Negotiation.find(:all, 
                 :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), 
                 :select => 'sum(amount_after_annualised_base) sum_amount,
                             sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / greatest(1,sum_amount) as pt').first
```

and check in your code if sum_amount is zero.

Comment: nice, using greatest(1,sum_amount) is the coolest way. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to write something like

```
Negotiation.find(
  :all, :conditions => conditions_hash('negotiation'), 
  :select => 'CASE sum(amount_after_annualised_base) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE sum(payment_term * amount_after_annualised_base) / sum(amount_after_annualised_base) END as pt').first
```

which would return NULL if `sum(amount_after_annualised_base)` is zero, and else does the requested division.