# ERROR: division by zero + PostgreSQL + Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, view

[image]

I'm getting the following error when I run this database view in psql (ERROR:  division by zero). Even I can't access my table in rails console If anyone has any solution for this error so please comment on it will be very helpful thanks in advance.

```
select 
      (exam_id || '00' || quarter)::bigint as id,
      account_id,
      exam_id,
      quarter,
      quarter_label,
      count(id) as assessments,
      max(banding_percentage) as top_assessment_percentage,
      min(banding_percentage) as bottom_assessment_percentage,
      round(avg(banding_percentage),2) as avg_assessment_percentage
    from report_assessments
    group by account_id, exam_id, quarter, quarter_label;
```

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154397/rails-prevent-division-by-zero-with-postgres

Comment: @JimJones Actually I didn't put that condition NULLIF I did the solution of my value which will never come 0.

Comment: If you have the full control of this variable, there is nothing to worry about. But in case it might be even remotely possible to get a zero in a division, the usage of nullif is imperative.

Comment: @JimJones Yes sure thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid running into `division by zero` exceptions you should use [`nullif`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nullif/), so that you can catch this `0` and replace it by `null`, e.g.

```
WITH j (v1,v2) AS (
  VALUES (1.0,0.0),(10.0,3.0)
) 
SELECT v1/nullif(v2,0) AS div FROM j;

        div         
--------------------

 3.3333333333333333
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: @ShubhamSingh . . . This is the canonical solution and the answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do something like this.
It works in my case:

```
Negotiation.find(
  :all, 
  conditions: conditions_hash('negotiation'),
  select: 
    'CASE 
      sum(banding_percentage) 
      WHEN 
        0 
      THEN 
        NULL 
      ELSE 
        sum(total_percentage) / sum(banding_percentage) 
      END as error_check'
).first
```

Comment: Can you check my screenshot I just uploaded unable to access my table from rails console